# Microsoft push notification service 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied

Tags: php, windows-phone-8, mpns

I am trying to send secure windows push notifications from my php server with valid ssl certificate and I got this error:

**403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.**

**You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.**

I uploaded certificate to dev.windowsphone.com and HttpNotificationChannel where serviceName is my Common Name from certificate. I got https uri from HttpNotificationChannel but when I call it from server I got error. Does anyone know what the problem is?

When I call unsecure request from server everything is ok.

Comment: I am not too sure if this helps but is there a ```HttpsNotificationChannel``` ? I am just thinking outside the box that perhaps it is like a web server trying to accept https traffic through a http port - there will be issues

Comment: that looks like directory permissions.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to allow access in the directory in Apache. Assuming you have super user access to the server, and I don't know how your server is set up, but you will need to set your directory like this:

```
<Directory "C:/Your/Directory/With/No/Trailing/Slash">
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```